# Get css by brand

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm new to using Tailwind-css and would like to know how I could get a different style sheet based on the environment key used.

I'm doing the following but I can't get the different colors:

**on `.env:`**

`NEXT_PUBLIC_THEME=brand_a`

**on `_app.js:`**

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-tailwind/react'

if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_THEME === 'brand_a') {
    require('../resource/env/brand_a/env.css')
} else {
    require('../resource/env/default/env.css')
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
    <ThemeProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
)

export default App
```

[This is my folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPHOv.png)

**stylesheet example:**

```css
    .btn-default-primary {
        background-color: theme('colors.primary');
        border-radius: theme('borderRadius.DEFAULT');
        color: theme('colors.primary-light');
        border-color: theme('borderColor.transparent');
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        padding-right: theme('padding.3');
        padding-left: theme('padding.3');
    }
    .btn-brand_a-primary {
        background-color: theme('colors.brand_a.primary');
        border-radius: theme('borderRadius.DEFAULT');
        color: theme('colors.brand_a.primary-light');
        border-color: theme('borderColor.transparent');
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        padding-right: theme('padding.3');
        padding-left: theme('padding.3');
    }
```

**using keys to import styles:**

```html
<Button type="submit" className={`ml-3 **!btn-${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_THEME}-primary** inline-flex items-center text-xs`}>
    Login
</Button>
```

**`tailwind.config.js`:**

```js
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                default: {
                    primary: '#205B3F',
                    'primary-light': '#DBE5E0',
                },
                brand_a: {
                    primary: '#496490',
                    'primary-light': '#F8F9FC',
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The principal problem is that you can't have dynamic class names like this:

```
btn-${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_THEME}-primary
```

Instead, you should have a conditional to set the string literal. An example with the classnames package:

```
className={cx('ml-3 inline-flex items-center text-xs btn-default-primary', {
  '!btn-brand_a-primary': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_THEME === 'brand_a',
  '!btn-brand_b-primary': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_THEME === 'brand_b'
})}
```

But this solution is not scalable.

You can add this plugin to manage different themes, witout creating a new class for everything you need. Adding customization to every theme and setting the theme you want in the HTML is enough to have multiple brand themes in the same application.

https://github.com/RyanClementsHax/tailwindcss-themer